# how to add a location tracking script on android?

Tags: rooting, geolocation, scripts

How can I add a custom script that retrieves the current location and also fetches current sim's cellphone number?

I want to root my phone and add a script that notifies me of its location and user every 10 minutes. So that even if the person resets my phone and manages to bypass frp I can still rely on the root script running in the backend.

I'm aware that they can just install a new rom though to get rid of the script

Comment: Before you reinvent the wheel: are you looking for something like [Cerberus](https://www.cerberusapp.com/) or [Prey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.prey)?

Comment: Apps can be uninstalled man, I want to create my own script that fetches my phone's location and gets the cllphone number of the sim card and ocassionally takes pictures when it gets unlocked. It will bundle all this data and email it to me. I don't believe this is primitive. It's like a backdoor to my own phone without the thief knowing.

Comment: You obviously didn't check. AFAIR *both* apps mentioned can be installed as hidden/camouflaged system apps if you have root access (at least they could when I last checked, which admittedly is a while ago), which is why I mentioned exactly *these* two (and no other). So removing these apps is not easier/harder than removing your script. But the apps already bring all the features you're after.

Comment: What you are looking for is definitely out of the scope of a shell script. At least you need to write a native service. But I don't think that location, phone number, camera and email features are available through native APIs (C++). Uaing Java APIs i.e. installing an app is the only option.

Comment: Thanks @IrfanLatif